# how to post json data by using asihttprequest

Tags: ios, json, asihttprequest

I intend to post json data :

```
NSString *newJSON = [theDictionary JSONRepresentation];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:ADDRESS,action]];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request appendPostData:[newJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request startSynchronous];
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

NSMutableDictionary* responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
NSLog(@"responseString = %@",responseString);
```

does the code work?did I miss some code?
I read the [asihttprequest tutorial](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use),and find it always post data with asiformdatarequest,what's the difference between asihttprequest and asiformdatarequest,if I just want to post json data,what should I do?thank you in advance.

UPDATE:yes,it works,but don't work well,I use some tool test the data,and receive some extra data:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.113
User-Agent: Ushi.com/1.0 CFNetwork/548.1.4 Darwin/11.3.0
Content-Length: 58
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code to see if it works?

Comment: That's not "extra data", that's the required HTTP header - it should definitely be there and is not a problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can post text data in json format like this

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"content-type" value:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"User-Agent" value:@"iPad"];
```

API itself sets user-agent although you can set it yourself too

```
request.allowCompressedResponse = NO;
request.useCookiePersistence = NO;
request.shouldCompressRequestBody = NO;
[request setPostBody:[NSMutableData dataWithData:[jsonRequest  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
[request startSynchronous];
```

Comment: It is more appropriate to set 'Content-Type' to 'application/json', if you are sending json.