# How to add JSON data with ASIHTTPRequest with post method?

Tags: json, asihttprequest

I got stuck on sending json string to my wcf rest web service using asihttprequest.
here is my code

```
NSString *jsonString=@"{\"user\":{\"EmailId\":\"bpsingh216@gmail.com\",\"Password\":\"kiran@123\",\"UserDetails\":{\"FirstName\":\"Kiran\",\"LastName\":\"Kuyate\"}}}";


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://182.72.47.242:52/UserService/MemberSignUp"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];  
[request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"content-type" value:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];
[request appendPostData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

can anyone plese guide me, where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can refer this one :

[how to post json data by using asihttprequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424681/how-to-post-json-data-by-using-asihttprequest)

Hope it will help you.